# Как закрыть Socket?

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет

есть отдельный поток класс который работает с Socket-ом.Когда я отключаю клиент он все равно продолжает работать. Метод `socket.isClosed()` возвращает `false` а `socket.isConnected()` `true` хотя клиент давно уже отрублен.Как можно закрыть этот Socket?  Есть мысли отправить сигнальный текст из клиента чтобы закрыть соединение типа :

```
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
   if(line.equals("exit")){
         socket.close();
     }
```

но я не могу использовать readLine() так как из клиента я отправляю только тогда когда получаю данные от сервера.Как это можно реализовать?помогите пожалуйста.Вот код который есть сейчас.На самом деле кода тут очень много ,я написал самую главную логику.

```
        @Override
        public void run() { 

                try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                           new InputStreamReader(
                                             socket.getInputStream(),
                                               Charset.forName("cp1251")))){

                 while(true) {

                        out.println("soobshenie s servera");
                        out.flush();

                      if((socket.isClosed())||(!socket.isConnected())){
                        socket.close();
                        System.out.println("поток завершен");
                        break;
                      }
                  } 
              }
        }
```

Comment: Самый надёжный способ - это отправить что-нибудь в сокет и закрыть его в случае ошибки отправки.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev проверить с  printWriter.checkError()?

Comment: Если попытаетесь писать в сокет, из которого некому прочитать, вылетит исключение. Его надо перехватить, закрыть сокет и удалить ссылку на него.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Методы `isConnected()` и `isClosed()` в **Java** работают немного не так, как вы представляете.

Метод `isConnected()` возвращает `true` тогда, когда сокет хоть раз был *connected*.
Даже если сокет уже давно закрыт, `isConnected()` будет `true`.

Метод `isClosed()` возвращает `true`, когда сокет был хоть раз закрыт. Если сокет никогда не был подключен, `isClosed()` вернет `false`, даже не смотря на то, что по факту он не открыт.

Следовательно, вот так вот можно проверить, подключен ли сокет к серверу на текущий момент.

```
boolean connected = socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed();
```